# Click Menu to call UserControl to MainWindow's Grid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I want to click the menu “Now Playing” then call UserControl to MainWindow's Grid

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Menu Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Height="30" Header="Now Playing" x:Name="NowPlaying" Click="NowPlaying_Click" />
        <MenuItem Height="30" Header="Music Library" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
        <MenuItem Height="30" Header="Play Schedule" />
        <MenuItem Height="30" Header="Control" />
        <MenuItem Height="30" Header="Option" />
    </Menu>
    <Grid Margin="0,30,0,0" x:Name="MainBoard">
        (UserControl"NowPlaying")
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.vb

```
Private Sub NowPlaying_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles NowPlaying.Click  
        Dim MainWindow = TryCast(System.Windows.Window.GetWindow(Me), MainWindow)
        Dim MainWindowBoard = MainWindow.MainBoard
        Dim NowPlayingBoard As UserControl = New NowPlaying
        #???
End Sub
```

UserControl.xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid Width="800" Margin="0,0,0,100"/>
        <Grid Margin="0,350,0,0" Background="#FFFFDADA">
            <Slider Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30"/>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add controls to a `Panel` e.g. `Grid` by using the `Panel.Children` property.

Your code can be simplified. As the event handler is defined in the code-behind, you already have direct access to all its fields and properties by simply using `Me`. Calling `Window.GetWindow` is redundant.

```
Private Sub NowPlaying_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim nowPlayingControl As UserControl = New NowPlaying()
    Me.MainBoard.Children.Add(nowPlayingControl)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

```
Private Sub NowPlaying_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles NowPlaying.Click
        Dim NowPlayingBoard As UserControl = New NowPlaying
        Me.MainBoard.Children.Clear()
        Me.MainBoard.Children.Add(NowPlayingBoard)
End Sub
```